# Arduino MP3 Player

Tags: arduino-uno, electronics, audio, sound

I want to make a MP3 player with arduino. My problem is what board should I use? There is the SparkFun MP3 Player Shield, SparkFun Audio-Sound Breakout - WTV020SD. Then I want to attach a 2.8 TFT touch screen to control volume,change track etc. Can I attach it to for example on top of MP3 player shield?I'm thinking in this one https://www.adafruit.com/products/1651. And finally what speakers can I use with which board? I want some good small speakers, two to be exact.

I don't really need help with electronics and programming. Just need to know wich are the best components that can work with each other without spending a lot of money. Thank you.

Best Regards

Comment: If you don't need help with electronics then you'll already know that you should be reading datasheets and schematics.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you do not use speakers but instead send the output to a 3.5mm stereo plug, so you can use headphones or speakers.

Is a 2.8" inch display really necessary?  You could probably get away with a 1" display and at a guess that would use less power.

Another idea may be to look at a Bluetooth interface for sending the sound to the headphones or speakers.

You could also look at a WIFI interface to provide additional control interface and to allow downloads straight to the device.  (ESP8266 would probably be the easiest interface).

Something you didn't mention was the power source.  Are you going to have internal batteries with a USB charging and power socket, so you can hook it to a PC or Batter Pack.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you the [VS1003](http://www.vlsi.fi/fileadmin/datasheets/vs1003.pdf) chip ($2.30 on ebay) or module ($7 on ebay). It can play MP3, WMA, MIDI, WAV and can record and encode ADPCM. It's even programmable (own filters etc). See [this project](http://arduino-cool.blogspot.com/2012/10/arduino-mp3-player-i.html).